# Как сделать стиль таблицы для рядков в Excel

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой инструмент или функцию нужно использовать, чтобы рядок чередовался и менял цвет на другой и так повторялось для всех рядков таблицы

Comment: Оформить диапазон умной таблицей

Answer (score 0):

Главная. Там форматировать как таблицу. Стиль средний 13.